# Failure passing plots to `saveHTML(){animation}` in R

Tags: r, animation, plot

## The background:

I am trying to create an animation with `saveHTML(){animation}` to show how runner's pace between two consecutive laps changes over time. I tried to pass the plots into the `expr` block with the following code:

```
MakeSpLaps <- function(finishers.pace, lap1, lap2, start.lap) {
    sp <- qplot(lap1, lap2, data=finishers.pace, 
                color=gender, alpha = I(.7) ) 

          # + additional elements removed;

    return(sp)
}

MakeSpLapsAnimation <- function(){
    brk <- seq(0, 3000, 60)
    lbl <- seconds_to_period(brk)
    oopt = ani.options(interval = 0.2, nmax = 20)
    saveHTML({
        par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.5, 0.5))
        for (i in 3:11){
            # The problematic line below
            MakeSpLaps(p, p[[i]], p[[i+1]], i-2) 
            ani.pause()
        }
    }, img.name = "lap_plot", imgdir = "lap_dir", htmlfile = "laps.html", 
        autobrowse = FALSE, title = "Plots of consecutive laps.", 
        description = "Plots of consecutive laps.")
}
```

Where the data.frame `p` looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   17051 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ bib       : int  10001 10003 10004 10005 10006 10009 10010 10011 10012 10013 ...
 $ gender    : Factor w/ 3 levels "","F","M": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ X5km_lap  : num  290 204 196 315 228 ...
 $ X10km_lap : num  280 204 201 322 225 ...
 $ X15km_lap : num  283 205 204 326 235 ...
 $ X20km_lap : num  282 206 204 342 229 ...
 $ X25km_lap : num  280 210 205 371 235 ...
 $ X30km_lap : num  280 225 216 407 254 ...
 $ X35km_lap : num  279 274 231 404 267 ...
 $ X40km_lap : num  284 251 257 357 262 ...
 $ Finish_lap: num  289 242 247 333 265 ...
```

## The problem and question:

Running `MakeSpLaps(p, p[[3]], p[[4]], 1)` alone creates the graph I want, but when I plug it to `saveHTML()`, no plot was created except for a blank PNG. The HTML files are created with the following warning. How can I correctly pass the plots to the function `saveHTML()`?

```
animation option 'nmax' changed: 20 --> 1
animation option 'nmax' changed: 1 --> 20
HTML file created at: laps.html
```

The actual code is here: https://github.com/hktang/rscraper/blob/3d542b18b5f6fbf1a1fa31b0bd3936f1179cdc59/r/visuals.R#L145

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. @slickrickulicious